# Altering table rows referenced by an unknown key

Tags: sql, postgresql

In **PostgreSQL** I have a table *one*, and another table *two*. In both there is some *id* column, and there exists a foreign key on *one.id* referencing *two.id*. What I want to do is drop the table *two* in such a way, that all row's in *one* have their id's set to null.

The problem is I don't want to modify the content of the table itself, only the stucture. I thought of setting the mentioned foreign key to be set null on delete, then delete all rows from *two*, and finally drop *two* (cascade), but the issue is, I don't know the constraint's name, so it would require using some advanced manipulation to get it out, which I'd like to avoid. **I have no direct access to the database, all I can do is execute a query on it. In particual I can't just check the foreign key's name.**

So my question is - is there a simple, quick way to do this?

Comment: Just look at the source (or definition) of the tables with your favourite SQL client and you will see the name of the foreign key.

Comment: If you can run queries you apparently have a SQL client, so you _can_ check for the constraint name.

Comment: It has to be just one query to be executed, not a serie of me querying - reading the database's response - querying again etc.

Comment: If you are limited to just a single statement, then how would you run `alter` to change the foreign key, `delete` all the rows and `drop` the table two? That's way more than just one statement.

Comment: I mean't one sequence of queries. I want something that runs **without** a human in the middle of the process to oversee.

Answer (score 0):

> there exists a foreign key on `one.id` referencing `two.id`

In that case, every row of `one` has an `id` that either already is `NULL` or that you want to set `NULL`.  The FK constraint means there can be no non -`NULL` value of that column that is not the `id` of a row of table `two`.

> What I want to do is drop the table `two` in such a way, that all row's in `one` have their id's set to `null`.

So what's wrong with

```
UPDATE one set id = NULL
```

?  Without a `WHERE` clause, all rows will be affected.  Or if you're not comfortable with that, then use `WHERE id IS NOT NULL`.

Obviously that won't work if `one.id` is the PK for table `one`, and likely not if it is one column of a multi-column PK, or etc., but in any of those cases what you propose to do doesn't work under any circumstances, no matter how you try to do it.

Comment: This is a part of an university assignment, and I'm forbidden to introduce any changes to the **content** (rather than changing the **stucture**) of the table. Although I'm free to look for help online, I found only solutions that either were too complex, or were using the name of our foreign key.